# File deleted with remove function still shows up in FindFirstFile/FindNextFile loop immediately following the removal. Why is this?

Tags: windows, file, winapi

In my application a file is deleted using the `remove` function.
If, immediately after the remove, I ask for the list of files in the folder, using `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`, the file still shows up in this list.  However, if I wait for a few seconds, the file is found anymore.

- Is this known behavior of Windows (files deleted asynchronously?)
- Or does `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` cache some information which is not immediately updated?
- Or can a virus scanner cause this strange behavior?

What is the best way to get a consistent result (so file not found anymore after remove)?

- Add a call to Sleep after remove?
- Use `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` after the remove and retry until the file is really deleted?
- Use a different method to delete a file? (could be Windows-specific)

Comment: The delete is synchronous. Does remove() return success? If the file is open already the delete will be deferred until the last handle is closed, so that could explain your symptoms

Comment: [remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2da4hk1d.aspx) calls [DeleteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915.aspx). The latter has more explicit documentation, on what is happening. Specifically, *"file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is closed"*. Any process (including AV software) can hold a handle to a file.

Comment: I am finding this same problem. The prior comment about file deletion not occurring until the last handle is closed I don't think is the issue. So the question hasn't received a satisfactory answer now for 2 years. In my case, Windows file explorer does not show the file, even with every possible file made visible through the Explorer view options. However, the file (or folder in my case) continues to be found by `FindFirstFile`. I used `SHFileOperation` to delete the folder. Subsequent attempt to delete the file in the same manner say that it doesn't exist.