# FindFirstFile/FindNextFile finds folder that has been deleted with SHFileOperation

Tags: windows, file, winapi

I am using `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` to show a list of files in a given folder in my application.

On occasion, I'm seeing cases where my application deletes a folder using `SHFileOperation`, but the folder can still be found by `FindFirstFile`. I've seen this problem reported previously on StackOverflow here: [File deleted with remove function still shows up in FindFirstFile/FindNextFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355237/file-deleted-with-remove-function-still-shows-up-in-findfirstfile-findnextfile-l). However, in my case I'm not using `remove` and the folder remains visible even after clearing the recycle bin. In addition, the folder is NOT visible in Windows file explorer. This makes me wonder what the file explorer is filtering on to ignore the file.

I tried looking at file attributes but only found that the deleted folder had `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL` set. The `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL` attribute is a bit mysterious (MSDN says it's reserved for system uses), so I tried ignoring folders that had that attribute set. However, it turns out that there are legitimate existing/active folders that have this attribute set, so I'm unable to use it as a filter.

Why is this folder showing up? How can I ignore it and not ignore existing (non-deleted) folders?

Comment: Did you remember to FindClose() ?

Comment: @AlexK. yes, I did.

Comment: Deleting a directory is a pretty hazardous affair, it is very often locked by another app.  Standard cases are it being the default working directory of another process, being observed by a FileSystemWatcher, a search indexer or anti-malware program plowing through the files in the directory.  All of which need to do *something* to avoid making it hard to delete the directory.  They open files and the directory handle with delete sharing.  Which allows a process to delete the directory.  But the files and dir won't disappear until the last handle is closed.

Comment: @HansPassant certainly there are cautions when deleting a folder. But I'll reiterate: if there's still a handle open on the folder and, therefore, can't be really deleted yet, why did the `SHFileObject` delete operation succeed, and why doesn't the folder show up in the Windows File Explorer? Clearly, that program is filtering this folder out in some way that isn't obvious looking at `FindFirstFile` documentation for attributes.

Comment: No special magic.  The nice thing about SHFileObject() is that it is a shell function and thus has no trouble letting Explorer know that it should hide the directory.  Check out the docs for SHChangeNotify() for the plumbing behind it.

Comment: @HansPassant my bad, I meant to say I used `SHFileOperation` for the delete, not `SHFileObject`. I couldn't find any documentation on something called `SHFileObject`. All the reading I've done @MSDN for retrieving file attributes all finally lead back to a file attribute DWORD which, in this case, just has the two bits I mentioned in my question set. I couldn't find any other hint from the Win API I could obtain about the file that would tell me that it shouldn't be available to the user as "virtually deleted".

Comment: If you can open a new handle for the directory with any access, including just to call `GetFileAttributes` on it, then it is not currently in a deleted state. If the underlying file/link/stream control block has a deleted disposition, then you can only access the file directly via handles for existing File objects. You can still get indirect meta-information from the parent directory via `FindFirstFile` or native `NtQueryDirectoryFile`.

Comment: @eryksun it's a very peculiar state. I rebooted my PC and checked in both Windows File Explorer (making hidden and system files visible) and using `dir` and `attrib` at the command line, and the folder didn't show up. However, in my application using `FindFirstFile`, the folder appeared. So from within my app, I tried a delete again (which uses `SHFileOperation` and it successfully deleted the folder. I'm still left puzzled why the folder was not visible from Windows File Explorer or the command line. The folder, by the way, was under `Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL` means it's a file/directory that exists virtually for a 32-bit application that's not manifested with a  `requestedExecutionLevel` and thus not [UAC aware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410). The real file/directory is located in the user's virtual file store "%LocalAppdata%\VirtualStore". You can check in the Task Manager or Process Explorer whether UAC virtualization is enabled for your application.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for explaining that attribute. What I found is that if I ignore folders with that attribute set, there are several "legitimate" folders under `Program Files (x86)` that get filtered out (they have the attribute set). This added a bit to my confusion. Regardless, I'm still left with not understanding the different between what `FindFirstFile` finds and what Windows File Explorer shows.

Comment: If your application is virtualized, it sees files in protected system directories that are actually in the user's `"%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore"`. Explorer won't see these virtual files because it's a 64-bit application that's UAC aware and thus not virtualized.

Comment: @eryksun ah ok, now we're getting somewhere. But I am not well educated on the virtualization aspects of Windows apps, so I guess I have a bunch of reading to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found this remark from the MSDN page,

[FindFirstFile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Be aware that some other thread or process could create or delete a
>   file with this name between the time you query for the result and the
>   time you act on the information. If this is a potential concern for
>   your application, one possible solution is to use the CreateFile
>   function with CREATE_NEW (which fails if the file exists) or
>   OPEN_EXISTING (which fails if the file does not exist).

It says you should double check for file is really there, using CreateFile API.